# Wordpress: editing child theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to edit some stuff on my website. I'm using a child theme and I plan to change some CSS and do some structural changes. I know the CSS is easy to change, as I only need to call the names of the classes or IDs and give the new values.

But, if I want to change things around in html, do I need to copy the whole code? Will I lose every change when the theme updates (as in: i copied and pasted the *older version* and now I need to copy and paste the *new version*)?

I don't know much about the names of things and how to describe them properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make copies of the theme files in the parent theme you want to modify - such as index.php, category.php, etc - and move those to the child theme and edit them. The copies in the child theme will be used by WordPress rather than the same-named files in the parent. This includes file in folders, i.e. `/css/style.css`, so duplicate the file structure in the child theme, if needed.

The child theme will continue to use those files, even if/when the parent theme get updated. And that also means your child theme edits won't disappear, unless there are major structural/functional changes to the parent theme.

One exception to child theme file usage is `functions.php`:

> Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child theme does not override
>   its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to
>   the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded right before
>   the parent’s file.)

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Wordpress Doc - Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files):

> If you want to change more than just the stylesheet, your child theme
>   can override any file in the parent theme: simply include a file of
>   the same name in the child theme directory, and it will override the
>   equivalent file in the parent theme directory when your site loads.
>   For instance, if you want to change the PHP code for the site header,
>   you can include a header.php in your child theme's directory, and that
>   file will be used instead of the parent theme's header.php.

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress Child Theme can't have a child theme itself. It's not supported by Wordpress. I had the same problem before and after some searches I found this [article](https://www.wp-code.com/wordpress-snippets/wordpress-grandchildren-themes/).

It explains about creating a grandchild theme; from the article:

> The solution is surprisingly simple. Instead of editing the child
>   theme, create a grandchild theme. It’s very similar to creating a
>   child theme, except you do it via a plugin. You add your custom
>   functions to the plugin, just as you normally would in functions.php
>   (though remember your plugin will be called much earlier than
>   functions.php, so you’ll need to make sure that any code in your
>   plugin only runs when an action is fired). Use the wp_register_style
>   and wp_enqueue_style functions to add your CSS (by default a
>   grandchild theme will add your CSS to the CSS of the parent or child
>   theme, but you can change this behaviour by using the wp_dequeue_style
>   function). Finally filter the result of the get_query_template
>   function to control which PHP files are executed when a page is
>   requested.

It's not really a child theme of a child theme, but a plugin including calls to `add_filters` or something similar to override the behaviour of the child theme. In this way upgrading child / parent themes will not affect the customisation you've made.